# Unix - find reciprocal column sets

Tags: unix

super newbish question here. I have a file with the following format:

```
A A 200
A B 100
A C 90
B B 203
B A 101
B C 87
C C 300
C A 91
C B 86
```

I would like to find reciprocal sets for columns 1 and 2 and then write the value of column 3 for the reciprocal set into column 4.

An example:

The second row `A B` has a reciprocal set, which is row 5 `B A`

So, I would like to make a script that would output for row 2:

```
A B 100 101
```

obvious some columns would not have reciprocals in which case I would like the 4th row to be 0.

Is this possible?

cheers!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This seems like it would be a trivial awk script, and even a simple bash script. What problem are you running into when you try to write them?

Comment: What would you expect for `A A`? `A A 200 200`?